# Operator << in c++ and gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

It should be given that I am a beginner, so the question may seems dumb.

I just look at someone's code ,and I don't know the meaning of the following line

```
EXPECT_EQ(input.getErrorNum(), 0) << input.getErrorMsg();
```

I don't know what is the meaning of operator << is that defined by gtest?

and

```
EXPECT_EQ()
```

is a macro defined by a test structure "gtest" provided by google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EXPECT_*](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#assertions)

> The assertions come in pairs that test the same thing but have
>   different effects on the current function. ASSERT_* versions generate
>   fatal failures when they fail, and abort the current function.
>   EXPECT_* versions generate nonfatal failures, which don't abort the
>   current function. Usually EXPECT_* are preferred, as they allow more
>   than one failures to be reported in a test.

Each `EXPECT_*` works like streams and you can use `<<` to print out some information about errors, exceptions and warnnings.